# Vue - Add elements outside of the loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am looping over a table row, but each of the table rows should have another table row attached to it in which other data from the loop should appear. I am unable to somehow insert

```
  <tr class="data-spacer"></tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="additional-data" colspan="3">Subjects: </td>
        <td class="additional-data" colspan="5">Classes: </td>
      </tr>
  <tr class="spacer"></tr>
```

after each looped row. I tried also just looping those elements for themselves as well, but they just get stacked after the first row's loop has produced all it's children, so the attached tr just gets stacked under the last one of the first loop's children.

Is there any way to overcome this? I really need to use a table for this.

```js
<table>
          <tr>
            <th>Photo</th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone number</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Subjects</th>
            <th>Classes</th>
            <th>Operation</th>
          </tr>
          <tr v-for="(teacher, i) in teachers" :key="i">
            <td><img id="profilePhoto" src="../../../assets/default_pic/user_green.svg" alt="profile-photo"></td>
            <td><input type="text" v-model="teacher.firstName"></td>
            <td><input type="text" v-model="teacher.lastName"></td>
            <td><input type="text" v-model="teacher.username"></td>
            <td><input type="text" v-model="teacher.email"></td>
            <td><input type="text" v-model="teacher.phoneNumber"></td>
            <td><span>F12</span></td>
            <td><span></span></td>
            <td><span></span></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data-spacer"></tr>
           <tr>
            <td class="additional-data" colspan="3">Subjects: </td>
            <td class="additional-data" colspan="5">Classes: </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="spacer"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wrap the headers inside <thead></thead> and all the rows inside <tbody></tbody>

Comment: Are you just asking how to create two `<tr>` elements for each item in the data array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added fixes to the above code. Try this one

```
<table>
<thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Photo</th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone number</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Subjects</th>
            <th>Classes</th>
            <th>Operation</th>
          </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<template v-for="(teacher, i) in teachers" :key="i">
          <tr>
            <td><img id="profilePhoto" src="../../../assets/default_pic/user_green.svg" alt="profile-photo"></td>
            <td><input type="text" v-model="teacher.firstName"></td>
            <td><input type="text" v-model="teacher.lastName"></td>
            <td><input type="text" v-model="teacher.username"></td>
            <td><input type="text" v-model="teacher.email"></td>
            <td><input type="text" v-model="teacher.phoneNumber"></td>
            <td><span>F12</span></td>
            <td><span></span></td>
            <td><span></span></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
</template>
          <tr class="data-spacer"></tr>
           <tr>
            <td class="additional-data" colspan="3">Subjects: </td>
            <td class="additional-data" colspan="5">Classes: </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="spacer"></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, your method almost worked. Problem was that it isn't allowed to key a template, but I've but the <tr>'s outisde the template into it and just added a key to each <tr> element and removed the key from the template. Works like a charm now. Thank you so much!